# What is a LaTeX root document?

Tags: kile, root

I am using **Kile** on the system **Ubuntu11.04** (and also a **Kile** user on Kubuntu 14.04). Whenever I am compiling a **tex** file with **kile**, it shows a message below:

[image]

I have a book document with a Master.tex file that contains:

```
% My Book Title % 
\input{./Preamble.tex} %Preamble
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\input{./TitlePage.tex}
\input{./CopyrightPage.tex}
\input{./DedicationPage.tex}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents{}
\mainmatter
    %...\input various %
    %...\chapters ...  %     
\end{document}
```

Please provide an explaination to this warning message and root documents.

Comment: Have you tried doing `sudo kile /path/to/document`?

Comment: The fact that is says "Preface.tex" (and says it isn't a root document) makes me think it's an input file for a bigger tex document (such as a book). Does Preface.tex begin with something like`\documentclass{article}` as (root) tex documents should?

Comment: @DJP my _Preface.tex_ begins with **\documentclass[twoside,custom]{tmc}**, where 'tmc' another file namely 'tmc.cls'

Comment: What does `file Preface.tex` say (from a terminal in the proper directory)?

Comment: @dustin I have tried it from terminal according to you but, it show an error :'The file /home/mks/Desktop/Preface(14_04_13) could not be loaded, as it was not possible to read from it.

Check if you have read access to this file.'

Comment: You need to escape the parentheses: `cd /home/mks/Desktop/Preface\(14_04_13\)/`; then `file Preface.tex`.  (I recommend *against* using parentheses in file and directory names, by the way: they are just as bad as having spaces in file and directory names. Stick to letters and numbers.)

Comment: Can you post a MWE? The parens in the path don't cause me problems. What exactly are you clicking on to get the error? If you create a new file does it persist? Finally what version of Kile are you using?

Comment: check if you have selected another document (even completely unrelated to the one you want to compile) as "master document". Click Settings, if the first entry of the menu says "normal mode" it means you have selected another document as master document. Remove the check and see if the warning goes away.

Comment: It is asking if you have read access to the file. chmod the file and give it read access.

Comment: I can't reproduce this from the information you've given. You'll need to explain more about your setup. I have seen this dialogue or a similar one in Kile but I can't remember what triggers it.

Comment: Kile expects the root document to contain the `\documentclass` command. Since it is hidden inside `preface.tex`, kile thinks, you want to call LaTeX on a file without `\documentclass`. There is an easy trick too convince Kile, that this is the right file, add `\iffalse\documentclass{article}\fi`, then Kile will see the `\documentclass` without knowing, it is never executed because of `\iffalse`.

Comment: The question is now clear and can be reopened.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I can't reproduce it, though. I tried everything I could think of, including creating a project containing the files and then trying to typeset the one starting `\input{preamble.tex}`. I also tried with and without the files-to-be-input existing. Nothing I did elicited any complaint from Kile at all. (Of course, TeX complained if the files didn't exist, but the point is that Kile ran `pdflatex` without complaint.)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I have Kile 4.14.9. Do you have something different?

Comment: @cfr Yes, I tested with a different version 2.1.0. Or the warning has been disabled, Also I noticed, that this version of Kile seems to scan the saved version rather than the editor contents.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Huh. That is fairly ancient, isn't it? Whether it is saved or not, Kile doesn't produce the warning for me. (I doubt I've disabled it, but I certainly can't rule it out.)

Comment: @cfr In my "ancient" version, the setting for the root check is stored in file `~/.kde/share/config/kilerc` under section `[Tool/LaTeX/Default]` with entry `checkForRoot=yes`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Sorry. It's all relative. It is just that people here frequently respond to OP's by telling them that, say, TL from last year is unmentionably old, so I was interested that you were using an old version of Kile. The file is now `~/.config/kilerc`, by the way. At least, on my system. sym linked from the old location under `~/.kde4/share/...`. I have `checkForRoot=yes` for some tools, and `checkForRoot=no` for others. For pdfLaTeX, it is `yes`. However, earlier under `Notification Messages`, there is also `showNotALaTeXRootDocumentWarning` and that is set `false` in my case.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Anyway, I think my copy of Kile is lying and it isn't really the version it claims at all. It seems more likely that it is really 2.1.3 and has merely deluded itself into believing that it is it is 4.14.9. In which case, yours is quite recent. (I'd expect mine to be more recent just because of the distro I use, but I was surprised that the version numbers differed as much as they seemed to.)

Comment: @cfr `kile -version` prints three versions numbers for `Qt`, `KDE Development Platform` and `Kile`. Maybe the `4.14.9` refers to the KDE version number.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek That seems to be right. It is confusing since that is not even the version of KDE I'm using! Do you have the `showNot...` thing? We need some more reopen votes...

Comment: @cfr I haven't `showNotALaTeXRootDocumentWarning`.

Comment: @dustin Suggesting people run applications with `sudo` is insane. Seriously, this is ridiculously bad advice.

Answer (score 6):

I could reproduce the problem with Kile 4.14.9:

Kile expects the root document to contain the `\documentclass` command. Since it is hidden inside `preface.tex`, Kile thinks, you want to call LaTeX on a file without `\documentclass`. There is an easy trick too convince Kile, that this is the right file, add

```
\iffalse\documentclass{article}\fi
```

at the top of the file. Kile now sees the `\documentclass`, because it does not evaluate the TeX macro code and does not know, that `\documentclass` is never executed in TeX because of `\iffalse`.